# Why are my overloaded functions not taking in variables? The purposes of this program get the results of dog years in human years

Tags: variables, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//functions to calculate dog age in human years
//d=d*16+31
//h=(d-31)/16
```

first function- calculating dog years using traditional method

```
int calcDogsAge(int dy)
{
    int d= d*7;
    cout<<d<<endl;
}
```

second function -calculating dog years using empirical method

```
int calcDogsAge(float dy)
{
    float g=(g*16)+31;
    cout<<g<<endl;
}
```

The variables in main are not going through the functions
The integers d and g are human years, which are to be converted to dog years using overloading

```
int main()
{   int d=1;
    float g=1;
    cout << "Hello User welcome to the dog years program" << endl;
    calcDogsAge(d);
    calcDogsAge(g);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to describe your problem? `Why are my overloaded functions not taking in variables?` What does this mean? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I edited. Its a logic error. Its not taking in the variables I have in main an putting them in the functions to get a result. The program runs but doesnt produce the intended result

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I edited. Its a logic error. Its not taking in the variables I have in main an putting them in the functions to get a result. The program runs but doesnt produce the intended result

Comment: You're not using `dy` anywhere in your functions.

Comment: The name of the arguments you're passing to the functions (g and d) are meaningless in the functions, because the name of the parameter they're receiving is dy, not g or d. Read the function code . int calcDogsAge(int dy) means that it's receiving a parameter named dy, and that's the parameter you should be using in the function code.